# What does it mean "to which they helped themselves" in the following sentence

Tags: meaning

> For many years members of that office had paid for the tea or coffee **to which they helped themselves** during the day by dropping money into an "honesty box".

I understand the meaning of the sentence, but could someone explain the grammar behind highlighted phrase? The wording seems kind of unusual to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly normal. *To help oneself to something* is an everyday idiom, meaning to take something (often food, but not necessarily) for one's own use, not waiting for somebody else to serve them or give permission.

Comment: Is it grammatically correct to use "... or coffee which they helped themselves *to* ..." in this sentence?

Comment: Yes. In speech, a lot of people prefer this construction to the _to which_ construction. Also, a lot of people would omit _which_, giving "or coffee they helped themselves to".